# Can't find simple way to wait asynchronously

Tags: f#

Let's say I need to perform some asynchronous operation and I need the result right now. If I were using C#, I'd just do it this way:

```
var contents = await File.ReadAllLinesAsync(...);
```

Important part here is that it is non-blocking operation.

I am aware of `Async.RunSynchronously`, but documentation suggests that it is **blocking** operation, meaning it no better than `Task.Result` from C#.

If I need to do the same in F#, how do I read file contents without blocking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the answer from Bartosz, the equivalent of using `await` inside an `async` method in F# is to use `let!` inside a computation expression block. If you are dealing with .NET tasks, you can use `task { ... }`; if you are dealing with F# async computations, then you can use `async { ... }`.

To use `async { .. }` you can also turn tasks into async computations using `Async.AwaitTask`:

```
let run () = async {
  let! contents = File.ReadAllLinesAsync "/path" |> Async.AwaitTask
  return contents
}
```

How to actually run the `run ()` function? First of all, there is no way to run the computation and wait for the result without blocking. If you need the result in a synchronous block of code, you'll just have to block. This is the same as with tasks - you can let them run and complete in the background, use them in another non-blocking task or block and wait.

If you are not inside another `async { .. }` block, the two things you can do are:

```
// Run the task, do something with the result and
// start the whole operation without blocking 
async { 
  let! result = run ()
  printf "%s" result }
|> Async.Start

// Block and wait for the result using RunSynchronously
let result = 
  run ()
  |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation! What I can't understand is why I can wait for results without blocking in C#, but can't in F#? Why is there such fundamental difference?

Comment: I'm sure you cannot do that in C# either (because that is the nature of asynchronous computations_. What would be the C# code you are thinking of?

Comment: Or do you mean using `await`? If so, then you are only allowed to do this in a method marked as `async` and that will, in turn, make this method return `Task`. So, this is exactly the same as wrapping F# code in `async { ... }` which will also make it reutrn `Async`, i.e. something that is a delayed computation.

Comment: I mean await, yes. In C# I can have bunch of async marked methods and await everything, and I never have to ask myself "do I block and wait for results or do I write continuation". In C#, I can just await everything and write code as if it is all synchronous. I'm trying to understand how to do the same in F#

Comment: In F#, it is exactly the same - you write code as it is all synchronous inside `async { .. }` block (equivalent of marking a method as `async`) and inside those block, you call other asynchronous code using `let!` (equivalent of `await`). For more details, this might help: http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-fsharp-async-intro.aspx/

Comment: @TomasPetricek What about context-switching? When Async.RunSynchronously is run against the outer run() function, will the thread be blocked while the inner async CE is awaiting File.ReadAllLinesAsync or will the runtime context-switch to enable other work to be done on the current thread in the meantime? I think this is what people struggle with: what are the context-switching guarantees provided by F#? I am using F# to develop a web api so these things really matter as getting it wrong will block other requests and greatly degrade throughput. PS: I purchased and loved your book, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick to Task Parallel Library:

```ml
open FSharp.Control.Tasks

let run () = task {
    let! contents = File.ReadAllLinesAsync "/path"
    return contents
}
```

Here `task { .. }` is similar to marking method as `async Task<T>` in C#, while combinators ending with `!` symbol (eg. `let!`) could be compared to `await`.

Without going too deep into implementation details, the main difference is that `task { .. }` is a computation expression, therefore it's pluggable - there's one existing by default in `FSharp.Control.Tasks` namespace, but there are also other implementations and libraries (such as [Ply](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ply/)) which sometimes offer different capabilities.

Comment: Is there a way to await F# native async(not task) without blocking?

Comment: For that, you would wrap the code in `async { ... }` and use `let!` inside the block, in exactly the same way as in the above answer.

Comment: @TomasPetricek If I have async{...} with let! inside, how do I actually run async itself without blocking? Can't find anything other then Async.RunSynchronously