# in an async{} block, does let! in f# frees up the thread while waiting for a response, like the await in c#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, f#

For example if I do in C#

`var myThing = await ComputeThingAsync();`

while ComputeThingAsync runs asynchronously, the calling thread is free to take up other tasks...

In F# if I do something like

```
let myThingAsync = async {
    let! myThing = ComputeThingAsync ()
    return myThing
} |> Async.RunAsynchronously
```

does the same thing happen ? While ComputeThingAsync computes, is my main thread is freed up to take up more tasks ?

Comment: don’t know f# quick google brought this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/async. `The Task<'T> type, with task { } expressions, which represents an executing .NET task.
In general, you should consider using task {…} over async {…} in new code if you're interoperating with .NET libraries that use tasks, and if you don't rely on asynchronous code tailcalls or implicit cancellation token propagation. ` - so going from there what you may be using is `task` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/task-expressions

Comment: this may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522447/how-do-i-await-an-async-method-in-f

Comment: here a newer question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69469385/cant-find-simple-way-to-wait-asynchronously